# About ServerSockets and Sockets

Tags: java

I m started networking in java and hava some questions.Can anyone clear these to me?
  What is the difference between sockets and server sockets?
  Is ServerSocket means something related to server?

Comment: Can we know which part of documentation of these classes and their constructors is unclear for you?

Comment: Anyway try to think about this scenario: Sockets are used to communicate with another sockets. Problem is that they specify address and port number of this other socket. How would you solve problem of "first socket"? Should all sockets specify with which socket they want to connect, or should there be another kind of sockets that will not specify this and will accept connection from all other sockets. Also where should be each kind of this sockets used (which should be used on client code, and which on server code)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I can explain it to you: A `ServerSocket` is the server-side socket. It needs an open port in your firewall and LISTEN for OTHER clients to connect to your computer. A 'normal' `Socket` just ASK a server for a connection. This does not need an open port in your firewall. Everything, that you do in the internet, requires, that your computer ASK a server in the internet, for a connection. But the server have to LISTEN for a connection. So with the `ServerSocket`, you can accept those requests and create a connection:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(<port>);
Socket client = server.accept();
```

This is the serverside code and it creates a ServerSocket to listen for connection requests and create a normal Socket to use this connection. A Client application will connect like this:

```
Socket skt = new Socket(<ip>, <port>);
```

This will also create a `socket`, that can use the connection. But it requires a `serverSocket`, that accepts the connection request.

Hope, that helped you

Cydhra

P.S English is not my mother language, so I am sorry for mistakes.

EDIT:

> Can u please explain me what does server.accept() do

This method waits until a client requests a connection. So if your application shall do something while waiting for connections, you should use a thread, because your programm will stop until server.accept() get a request.

server.accept() waits for a client requesting a connection with this server on the specified port. When a client requests such a connection, the accept()-Method will return a instance of Socket, that represent the Client. It contains the Input- and Output-Streams, that can be used to send and recieve data from the client.

```
Socket skt = new Socket(<port>, <ip>);
```

This is the code of the client, as I posted above. It also contains the input- and outputstreams. Everything, that you write in the OutputStream of one Socket, will be recieved by the InputStream, of the other Socket. The Sockets are like Files, with two ends: On one end, you write in, on the other side, you can read the written.

Comment: Thanks a lot it really helped me. Can u please explain me what does server.accept() do. Does it create a socket between server and client when the client request to do so?